# Web site menu accessibility (one works, one does not)

Tags: css, wordpress, menu, accessibility

This is driving me bonkers!  I have two sites that I'm working on that are very similar and share a substantial amount of code.  Both menus work by mouse (hover), but one menu fails to expose submenus on tab (focus).  I'm 99% sure there is something glaringly obvious that I'm missing.

Broken:
https://onward2opportunity-vctp.org/

Works:
https://americaserves.org/

Another set of eyes would be most helpful and appreciated!

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.

Answer (score 1):

Just a quick look shows that 'americaserves' (works) has a focus/blur event handler but 'onward' (broken) does not.  I'm assuming the focus handler is what's displaying the submenu.

However, as a sidenote regarding keyboard accessibility, having submenus appear onfocus can make for a lot of tab stops.  If I'm trying to tab across the menu to get to the last item, I have to tab through all the submenus because they automatically appear.

A nice approach is to have a visual indicator that there's a submenu and use the `aria-expanded` attribute on the menu and set it to true/false depending on whether the menu is expanded/collapsed (respectively).  Let the user select the menu to open it rather than automatically opening.

However, once caveat is that your top-level menu items actually perform two purposes.  You can select the menu item itself and be taken to a page, or you can select the menu item to display the submenu.  Since you can't have two behaviors occur with the same interaction (<kbd>enter</kbd> key), you'd need separate elements.  This is typically done by having the menu text be a link that takes you to another page and then a small 'down arrow' type button next to it that displays the submenu.

You can still support hovering with a mouse displaying the menu.  And the extra 'down arrow' button could be hidden until it's tabbed to, similar to your skip links.

Comment: Hi @slugolicious, thanks for your input on this and sorry I have been absent for this amount of time.  Got drawn into another project...  Can you clarify what you mean by focus handler?

Comment: The `<a>` for "Who we are" on "americaserves.org" has an onFocus handler.  Just inspect the code in the browser and you'll see it.  It points to https://americaserves.org/wp-content/themes/3RF-Site-child/js/jquery.accessible-menu.js?ver=1.0.0.  I suspect when you tab to "Who we are" that the focus handler runs and displays the submenu.